how can i make the injector of route in angular
when i use the router link i have this error :
chunk-PXXAIYND.js?v=9a9432b3:48
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute -> ActivatedRoute]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute!
i try to injecte it correctly but still anabel to make it run , this is the code of the angulau prjct :
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { WeatherService } from '../weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-day',
  imports: [ActivatedRoute,WeatherService,RouterModule],
  templateUrl: './day.component.html',
  styleUrl: './day.component.css'
})
export class DayComponent implements OnInit{
  city: string = '';
  date: string = '';
  hourlyData: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private weatherService: WeatherService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.city = params['city'];
      this.date = params['date'];
      console.log(`City: ${this.city}, Date: ${this.date}`);
      this.getHourlyWeather();
    });
  }

  getHourlyWeather() {
    this.weatherService.getWeather(this.city).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log('API Response:', data);  // Log the data to inspect the structure
        const day = data.forecast.forecastday.find((d: any) => d.date === this.date);
        if (day && day.hour && day.hour.length > 0) {
          this.hourlyData = day.hour;  // Populate hourlyData with hourly forecast
        } else {
          console.error('No hourly data found for this date.');
          this.hourlyData = [];  // Set to empty array if no data is found
        }
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error('Error fetching hourly data:', err);
      },
    });
  }

weather.component.html
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [routerLink]="['/day', day.city, day.date]">Voir Plus</button>

weather.service.ts :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {
  private apiKey = ''; 
  private apiUrl = ''
;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  getWeather(city: string, days: number = 7): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}?key=${this.apiKey}&q=${city}&days=${days}`;
    console.log('API Request URL:', url);
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}



app.module.ts :
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes  } from '@angular/router';
import { DayComponent } from './day/day.component';
import { WeatherComponent } from './weather/weather.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: WeatherComponent },
  { path: 'day/:city/:date', component: DayComponent },
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  
  imports: [
    BrowserModule ,RouterModule.forRoot(routes),DayComponent,WeatherComponent
  ],
  providers: [provideHttpClient()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}



The ActivatedRoute is not a component/module/directive/pipe and should not be added to imports array, hence you are getting the issue. You can directly use it either using inject or through the constructor.
import { Component ,OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { WeatherService } from '../weather.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-day',
  imports: [
    // ActivatedRoute, // <- remove this!
    WeatherService,
    RouterModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './day.component.html',
  styleUrl: './day.component.css'
})
export class DayComponent implements OnInit {
  // private route: ActivatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  ...
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ...

